# Select top row based on a column - sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

We have the following data, I want to select the top rows based on the following data.

**Raw Data:**

[image]

I need to get the data in the following way, i need the top row for each projectID.

**Output:**

[image]

Please let me know how to write query to achieve this data.

Comment: Is there any colum on which you can base the order of rows with same project id?

Comment: i just need the top row. raw data brings the order by default which is correct. No need to consider other order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;with cte_getlatest as(
select row_number over (partition by ProjectID) as ROWNUM,
ProjectID,
PhaseID,
WBSJobNum
FROM
[TableName]
)
SELECT * FROM cte_getlatest WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Note that the physical order of the rows in the table will not always be the same as returned by a query without any specified `ORDER BY` list. This is well documented here - [SQL Order By](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19203/storage-order-vs-result-order)